# Mage.ai in Docker with MYSQL in Docker 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '*********:33060' (99)

Tags: mysql, docker, imageai

I am using a data pipeline tool and I'm trying to integrate with a MYSQL database in Docker "local-mysql" that has its own container on port 3306.  While the  data pipeline tool called Mage.AI is also in Docker in it's own container.  How can I connect the data pipeline tool to see the "local-mysql" container?

see configs I have in the tool below:

```
database: kdtestdb
host: localhost
port: 3306
username: root
password: mypassword
connection_method: direct
ssh_host: null
ssh_port: 22
ssh_username: null
ssh_password: null
ssh_pkey: null
```

PS: I created my mysql container with this command:

```
docker run --name local-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest
```

Comment: Change `host: localhost` to `host: local-mysql`

Comment: @user1191247  I tried that already and get  this error:

Failed to connect, see error below. 
2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '***********' (-2)

Comment: This solution by Thomasleveil solved by issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=2

Answer (score 1):

This solution by [Thomasleveil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107049/thomasleveil) solved by problem:

[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=2)

i.e. `host.docker.internal`